# Social voting on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, datastore, voting-system

I have an app where users can upvote or downvote a blog post. To implement the voting functionality, I created the below model ...

```
 class Upvote(ndb.Model):
   user_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
   blog_id = ndb.IntegerProperty(required=True)
```

When an user upvotes a post, I save it via:

```
Upvote(user_id=User.key.id(), blog_id=Blog.key.id()).put()
```

And to see if an user has already upvoted I query:

```
Upvote.query(Upvote.user_id=User.key.id(), Upvote.blog_id=Blog.key.id())
```

Is this the most efficient way to implement such a voting system? I want to make sure as it seems the `Upvote` model can get very large. Of course I am prematurely optimizing now but in a theoretical situation with millions of users I want the most efficient/cheapest method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one I'd call the model just `Vote` and I'd add a `BooleanProperty` called `upvote`, set to `True` if it's an upvote and set to `False` if it's a downvote.

Otherwise you'd have to repeat the story for downvotes and without some extra logic you'd leave room for a user to cast 2 votes, one up and one down, for the same post, which IMHO doesn't make a lot of sense.

Yes, there could be many `Vote` entities, but they are small and not related to each-other, scaling pretty good.